# How to overwrite shapefile layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.14

I'm modifying the Arrows plugin by Gregoire Piffault. It writes the output to a shapefile, but if the shapefile already exists it fails. He tries to remove the file using `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer` then write a new one using `QgsVectorFileWriter`, which results in an empty file; if the file doesn't already exist it works fine.

I've tried simply deleting the file using `os.remove` after the call to removeMapLayer, but the file is still locked.

```
os.remove(self.conf["arrow_outshape"])
        WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: u'C:/GIS/SK/Saskatoon/mpArrows.shp
```

I think there are two options:

1. change the code substantially to allow for editing the existing file rather than creating a new one if it already is loaded
2. figure out how to completely unload the file after removing the map layer so that I can delete it

Answer (score 1):

In a plugin of mine I have a similair problem and I use the ogr library to delete shape files. You could try something like this:

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
driver.DeleteDataSource('path_to_your_shape.shp')
```

More informations about python and ogr you can find here:
[osgeo.ogr](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-module.html)

Comment: this works sometimes. Other times I get an `OGRERR_NOT_ENOUGH_DATA` error on the call to `DeleteDataSource`. Can't really pin down what determines success but if I restart QGis I can generally run through it twice before it will fail!

Comment: I get the same problem as you @marcp, did you find another way to delete an existing shapefile or perhaps find a way to overwrite an existing file using QgsVectorFileWriter?

Comment: No I never sid, @15step. Once I struggled through that project I never needed that plugin again.